# Spacemacs: How can I customize the highlight style of a matching parenthesis?

Tags: spacemacs, highlighting, parentheses

How do I change, in my `.spacemacs`, the style used to highlight the matching parenthesis?

Comment: just install rainbow-delimeters and be happy.

Comment: I’m already using rainbow delimiters. I just need the highlight of the matching parenthesis the cursor is currently on. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a list with all the colors set by emacs with <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>list-faces-display</kbd> RET.

There you can search for the faces corresponding to parenthesis matching: `show-paren-match` in this case. If you click on it to customize it, test it or even save it. If you choose to save, this setting will be saved to your *custom-file* (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>custom-file</kbd>RET - for more info).

If you want to directly set the face in your `.spacemacs` you could use `custom-set-faces`

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(show-paren-match ((t (:foreground "white" :background "red")))))
```

or use your theme name with `custom-theme-set-faces`:

```
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'your-theme-name-here ;; e.g. 'spacemacs-dark
 '(show-paren-match ((t (:foreground "white" :background "red")))))
```

or by using the [theming layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bthemes/theming)

```
(setq theming-modifications 
'((your-theme-name ;; e.g. spacemacs-dark
       (default :foreground "white" :background "red"))))
```

or by using `set-face-attribute`

```
(set-face-attribute 'show-paren-match nil :foreground "white" :background "red")
```

Comment: That should be the right answer but I tried it and it doesn't have any effect.. Something must be overriding it after my setting it in `.spacemacs`. Do you know of a way to troubleshoot?

Comment: I have added some more info to the response.

Comment: Thank you. This is great info! Unfortunately it's still not working. I have no idea what is going on. There must be something taking over so will have to try it after I remove other parts of my configuration. I will accept your answer anyway as this is all someone needs to know to make it work under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Would leave comment but don't have the reputation yet. For me it was `Highlight-Parentheses` minor mode. I use spacemacs so its likely what was bothering you too.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It highlights too many pairs of parens. Thanks for the answer!